# Is using sequence in db2 statements possible?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to execute following statement in DB2.

This works well.

```
SELECT  NEXT VALUE FOR SCPYMNT.REM_QUERY_NO_SEQ 
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

However, this throws a database error.

```
SELECT  ( 
        CASE  WHEN PYMT_SYS = 1 THEN NEXT VALUE FOR SCPYMNT.REM_QUERY_NO_SEQ 
              WHEN PYMT_SYS = 2 THEN 'dummy' 
              else 'dummy' 
        END )   

FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

So Db2 gives the error below.

```
Category    Timestamp   Message
Statusbar   18.04.2016 11:47:39 DB2 Database Error: ERROR [428F9] [IBM][DB2] SQL0348N "NEXT VALUE FOR SCPYMNT.REM_QUERY_NO_SEQ" cannot be specified in this context. SQLSTATE=428F9
```

It seems to me there is not a syntax error.Does Db2 not let such queries that consists of case conditions and sequence?

@MichaelTiefenbacher,I put select examples as a demonstration.(What I am really trying to achieve is something like below.

```
SELECT NAME, QUERYNO
  FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO EMPSAMP (NAME, SALARY, QUERYNO)
                    VALUES('Mary Smith', 35000.00, 

CASE  WHEN PYMT_SYS = 1 THEN NEXT VALUE FOR REM_SEQ
CASE WHEN PYMT_SYS = 2 NEXT VALUE FOR EFT_SEQ 

));
```

I think question is more clearer now.

Comment: Is this trigger code?

Comment: No.It just first makes a selection with respect to PYMT_SYS and then try to return sequence value.

Answer (score 0):

Sequences can be used to generate unique keys or numbers when inserting data into tables. 
They are not used to generate unique numbers when selecting data. 
For that you could either retrieve the field from the table where you used the sequence at insert time or you can use row_number() in the SELECT.

It also would be helpful to tell a little more what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the answer is "No" according to IBM documentation.

> NEXT VALUE expressions cannot be specified in the following contexts:
>   CASE expression

Here is the [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00348n.html)

Answer (score 0):

Insert from a union of selects:

```
SELECT NAME, QUERYNO
FROM FINAL TABLE 
(
INSERT INTO EMPSAMP 
SELECT
 'Mary Smith', 35000.00, NEXT VALUE FOR REM_SEQ
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
WHERE PYMT_SYS = 1
UNION ALL
 'Mary Smith', 35000.00, NEXT VALUE FOR EFT_SEQ
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
WHERE PYMT_SYS = 2
)
```